# javascript:function_name() on onclick doesn't work on IE11

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a function like that:

`function alertName() {
   alert ("I am superman!")
}`

Called in a button like this:
`<button onclick='javascript:alertName()'>Click to get name!</button>`

This works in chrome but doesn't in `IE11`, sometimes it works for the first time but doesn't work after that.

Thanks

Comment: That's not valid html. The `onclick` shouldn't be in the `href`, it should be it's own attribute

Comment: Sorry man. That was a typo. Edited the question

Comment: Is that the actual function that doesn't work? Or does the real function do other stuff?

Comment: Does `onclick='alertName()'` work? Because you should not be or need to be putting `"javascript:"` in there anyways for `onclick`. Along with this can you give a snippet or fiddle showing this behavior?

Comment: Unless you can post code that reproduces the behaviour, this should be closed. Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: After I remove `javascript`, it does work. Do you know why it doesn't work with `javascript:` ?

Comment: @sachitad Because `javascript:` is supposed to only be used when indicating a link such as `href` is using JavaScript rather than being a URL. But attributes such as `onclick` expect only JavaScript, some browsers may *"know"* (*such as Chrome*) how to interpret that but it's not expected functionality. The currently deleted answer is still technically correct despite the initial typo.

Comment: Thank you spencer.